# Gratis, portable alternative to Agent Ransack (find text in files & display a few lines before & after)

Tags: windows, gratis, portable, text-search

[Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) does what I want. It recursively searches files, finds those that contain a given string, and displays portions of each find, with a configurable number of lines fore and aft for context.

I am looking for a gratis, portable, Windows app with the same functionality.  Note that a portable version of Agent Ransack won't cut the mustard, as the admin has blocked it.

I cannot use anything that need to be installed, or writes to the registry, and I don't want anything that builds a database of files for speed. Searching text fiels will suffice. Searhcing PDF/Office files would be a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dnGrep](https://dngrep.github.io/) might be something you're looking for.

- it supports configurable context lines before/after results
- it's fully portable - see [.zip releases](https://github.com/dnGrep/dnGrep/releases)
- it's free/open source
- it supports PDF/office files

Comment: This is excetly what I was lookign for. But ***better***!!  If you are the DN of dnGrep, you could charge money for this.

Comment: Don't know what DN is, but I'm not associated with that software in any way.  Glad it helped though.

Comment: It's my bets new find in a log, long time. Thanks again

Comment: Wow ! It has scripting too!  This just gets better & better